# app runs on one device but not another

Tags: android

**FIXED**

For some reason the special menu i created was killing it... THere was no API's or anything in that class. But thanks for the support guys

---

So this really isnt a question about a code but a very random error...

My app runs perfectly on my Nexus S rooted, but when it runs on any other phone or the emulator it will instantly FC.

The app does have root permissions but only if you choose to use it. Otherwise it is just a normal application.

Does anyone have a solution to why it would run on one device but not another?

-EDIT-

```
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104): java.lang.VerifyError: com.SyndicateApps.OmegaLauncher.Launcher
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1056)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2752)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2859)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:136)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2179)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5073)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-27 17:28:37.734: E/AndroidRuntime(7104):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

- EDIT 2 -

So its on 2.2 but same problem... Is there a way i can find the class using the api level 9?

LOGCAT 2 (on android 2.2)

- EDIT 2 / SECOND LOGCAT ON 2.2 EMULATOR -

11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258): java.lang.VerifyError: com.SyndicateApps.OmegaLauncher.Launcher
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-27 18:56:12.159: E/AndroidRuntime(258):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

A lot of the errors are when it comes to this... --> (new DialogInterface.OnShowListener()

Comment: Please include the logcat result especially for those FC exceptions

Comment: Have you tried the app on another phone running the same Android OS version?

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.VerifyError` typically means you're using a class or method that's not available on the current Java VM. Which Android version is on Nexus and which is on the other device? Android app manifest system allows for compiling against, say, API level 10 while allowing running against API level 6. There will be no warning against using backwards-incompatible classes until you run.

EDIT: So apparently the class `com.SyndicateApps.OmegaLauncher.Launcher` uses some API that was introduced in level 9. In the project properties, under "Android", set build target (temporarily) to Android 2.2 and see where the errors occur.

EDIT2: if the static analysis fails, try commenting out method insides in the class, method by method, until it loads. `VerifyError` is fairly easy to debug that way - it's triggered by very existence of faulty code in the class, not by its invokation. It's not like you have to do 100% coverage analysis.

Comment: I have Android 2.3.7 and the other devices have 2.2.1. Any idea what to look for to fix it?

Comment: Nevermind! It is running perfectly on the 2.3 emulator! But the min SDK version is 5. So any solutions??

Comment: It FC's on 2.2 emulator and devices

Comment: the api level was already set to 2.2. If i go to 2.1, then it will get a few errors. Does the option for root users to reboot throw off the api or unrooted devices?

Comment: So i should comment out the error areas or all the methods? the launcher.java file is about 15k lines so i hope you mean the trouble areas